# SPEC %files attribute and Shell variables

Tags: linux, fedora, rhel, rpm

I have a spec file which unpacks a library which is deployed at location which is exported in the shell.

ie

```
%file
${AXIS2_C}/bin/services/services.xml
```

This fails with :

```
error: File not found: root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/i386/${AXIS2_C}/bin/services/services.xml
```

I.e the shell variable does not get expanded. Is there any way around this ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, anything defined in the shell started by the %prep, %build or %install sections isn't preserved in the build environment.  You'd need to define %{AXIS2_C}, a *MACRO* variable (not a shell variable):

```
%define AXIS2_C /usr/local/something
```

and then refer to it in both your shells as

```
make whatever FOO=%{AXIS2_C} # or however you used the env variable
```

and then in the %files section, use

```
%file
%{AXIS2_C}/bin/services/services.xml
```

Usually, the initial %define is at the top of the spec file, with some documentation about what it is for.  If you need to dynamically set the macro, you'll have to use more complex RPM spec macro commands like %() to do shell expansions.

Comment: Cheers! This got it done. %define AXISHOME %(echo ${AXIS2C_HOME})

Comment: %file %AXISHOME/blah.xml

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you do not enclosure it in `{ }`, and only use `" "`

```
%file
"$AXIS2_C"/bin/services/services.xml
```

(or even without `" "` at all)

Comment: Tried and failed :(