# how to manage %files section in spec without environment variables

Tags: fedora, rpm, packaging, mpi

I am creating a package for a software using `MPICH`. The binaries must be installed on the [mpich directory](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/MPI/). This directory depends on the mpich version (`/usr/lib64/mpich-3.2/` or `/usr/lib64/mpich/`). For the `%install` section, I managed with variables `MPI_BIN` and `MPI_LIB` setting by macro. But these variables are not expanded in the `%files` section.

How can I list the binaries in the `%files` section ?
I have read an [old post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6601/spec-files-attribute-and-shell-variables) but the solution doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%files` can read a list of filenames from a file created during the installation process, when you have the variables you need. Eg

```
%install
echo /$MPI_BIN/somefile >>myfilelist
```

and then use

```
%files -f myfilelist
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `$MPI_LIB` has the scope only in `%install` section. You can try macros:

```
%install
MPI_LIB=some_value
%global mpi_lib $MPI_LIB

%files
/usr/lib64/%{mpi_lib}
```

But this fails because the definition of macros is evaluated at the very beginning of parsing the spec file. Therefore even before running `%install` section.

I would use this:

```
%global mpi_lib %(echo -n "mpich3")

%files
/usr/lib64/%{mpi_lib}
```

The construct `%( )` will run the content as a shell script and the output is used as the value of the macro.

Comment: This solution is not suitable for my problem :   `MPI_LIB` is set by macro, and as far I know, macros can't be used outside `%pre`  `%install` or `%post` sections.

Comment: ??? macro can be used anywhere in spec file. You just need to be aware that macro is interpreted in **build** time.